# How to combine 2 or more different models to predict one response variables?

Tags: r, model

I think one independent variables is so importance and primary that I want to use only it to build a model and use rest of other variables to build other models.

Such as in Titanic competition on kaggle.com,
I respect `sex` as a primary variables, and I used it to build a SVM model.
Then I used rest of other variables such as `fare`, `alone`, `age` to build a cforest model.

But to predict `survival`, I need both of them.
So how can i do so?
`lm()` function seems not to apply to `S4 class`.

My code here:

```
## Modeling Begin

predictions <- NULL
NT <- 1000
## formula3 for 'gender' model using SVM
formula3 <- as.factor(survived) ~ pclass + sex
## formula1 and formula2 both for rest features without gender model
formula1.cf <- as.formula(as.factor(survived) ~ pclass  + alone + fare + age)
formula2.cf <- as.formula(          survived  ~ pclass  + alone + fare + age)

## Train SVM(only for gender model) and Predict
library(e1071)
formula3 <- as.factor(survived) ~ pclass + sex
tune <- tune.svm(formula3, data=clean.train, gamma=10^(-4:-1), cost=10^(1:4))
# summary(tune)
tune$best.parameters

model.svm <- svm(formula3, 
               data=clean.train, 
               type="C-classification", 
               kernel="radial", 
               probability=T, 
               gamma=tune$best.parameters$gamma, 
               cost=tune$best.parameters$cost)

## Train cForest
model.cforest <- cforest(formula2.cf, data=clean.train, 
                           control=cforest_unbiased(ntree=NT, trace=F))
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I thought there was a combine(...) function now add into R's `randomForest` package which is used specifically for combining multiple random tree models. Also something as simple as the following code can be a means to combine linear and `randomForest` models. It is as simple as weighting each models influence.

#### Fit log regression and random forest:

```
fit.lr = glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, family = binomial, data = d)
fit.rf = randomForest(as.factor(y)~x1+x2+x3+x4, data = d, ntree = 100, proximity = FALSE)
```

#### Create functions in x1, x2 to give model predictions while setting x3, x4 at origin

```
g.lr.sig = function(x, y) predict(fit.lr, data.frame(x1 = x, x2 = y, x3 = 0, x4 = 0), type = "response") <br>
g.rf.sig = function(x, y) predict(fit.rf, data.frame(x1 = x, x2 = y, x3 = 0, x4 = 0), type = "prob")[, 2] <br>
g.en.sig = function(x, y) 0.5*g.lr.sig(x, y) + 0.5*g.rf.sig(x, y)<br>
```

I hope that helps.